# App gives an error "could not be installed at this time" on Phone Gap - Provisioning / Certificate

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, certificate, provisioning

I have created an app and uploaded it via "build.phonegap.com". It's quite intuitive and easy and I uploaded my source files in Zip on it. When made the build and then initiated the IPA to install it on iPad, it stops half-way and says "could not be installed at this time".

To be precise, it says:-

```
Unable to download application

"AppName" could not be installed at this time.
```

I've no clue where I am screwing things up as I made the Provisioning and Certificates again and again and then use the AdHoc Distribution Provisions and Distribution p12 files ...

P.S. I am installing the App on my company's iPad and this App is only internal and should be installed on around 25 iPads for presentation purpose only. Do you think I have any other option or something on my company's iPad is creating some barrier?

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have experienced similar issues as well.  There are a number of possible issues that could cause this specific problem, but the easiest way to determine the cause of your specific issue is to connect your iPad to your Mac, and check the Console for the device. This can be done by, opening up XCode, and from the `Window` menu, selecting `Organizer`. When the Organizer pops up, select the `Devices` mode. On the left side, you should see a section for the iPad. Attempt to install it and you should see the errors. Post them, and we can probably help resolve.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, your post guided me to the logs for the same problem on my ipod touch.